# How to use the Same Validator in Model and Template Based Controllers

Tags: templates, angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I have a custom Validator in my Model driven Forms that does validation.

Template -

```
<form [formGroup] = "myForm" (ngSubmit) = "save(myForm.value)">

            <div>
                <label>Name</label>
                <input type="text" formControlName="name">
            </div>
             <p *ngIf="myForm.controls.name?.errors">This has to be rahulsingh!</p>
             <button type = "submit" > Submit</button>
        </form>
```

Component -

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
            name: ['', [this.validateName]]          
        });


validateName(c: FormControl) {
    return (c.value === 'rahulSingh') ? null : {
        notCorrect: true
    };
}
```

This works for Model Driven Forms

But how to use this same Validation function for Template Driven

I am following this link http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/03/21/template-driven-forms-in-angular-2.html

But i am not able to understand How to make this function Global for both forms and use it as a directive . I always end up getting a wierd error trying to achieve this.

Also One wierd thing is in my template when i try to do

```
<p *ngIf="myForm.hasErrors('notCorrect')">This has to be rahulsingh!</p>
```

i get Cannot read property 'hasError' of undefined .

Comment: Even I have same doubt, Please any one help us

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start, we'll build out the directive that will be applicable to a Template Driven Form which will automatically make it applicable to a Reactive Form (neat trick):

```
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, NG_VALIDATORS, Validator } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[requiredName][ngModel]',
  providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: SpecificNameValidatorDirective, multi: true}]
})
export class SpecificNameValidatorDirective implements Validator {
  private valFn = (c: FormControl, name: string) {
    return (c.value === name) ? null : {
        notCorrect: true
    };
  }

  @Input('requiredName') name: string = "temp";

  constructor() {
  }

  validate(control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} {
    console.log("validation station", this.name, control.value);
    return this.valFn(control, this.name);
  }
}
```

There's a twist here in that name is not hard coded, though a default value is provided which means we can use the directive in a template driven form like so:

```
<form #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(myForm.value)">
    <div>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input requiredName="rahulSingh" name="name" ngModel #name="ngModel" type="text" id="name">
    </div>
     <p *ngIf="name.errors?.notCorrect">This has to be rahulSingh!</p>
     <button type="submit"> Submit</button>
</form>
```

Straightforward enough for the template driven form.

For the Reactive Form we can instantiate an instance of the directive:

```
var validator = new SpecificNameValidatorDirective();
```

and set the name we want

```
validator.name = "nobdy";
```

and then build our form with our instance of the directive:

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
          name: ['',[validator]]
      });
```

This will automagically look for the `validate` function and execute it as the various Validators all follow the [Validator interface definition](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/821b8f09d6054261c737f30ce500d912d7d8017e/modules/%40angular/forms/src/directives/validators.ts). The janky part is setting the name in a separate line instead of in the constructor but I have been unable to make that play nice with the template driven version.

Anyways, there's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/avik8ouNCTNuQAp6Hvbh?p=preview) available for you to mess around with.

Answer (score 1):

You can export functions in the same way as classes:

```
export const validateName:ValidateFn = (c: FormControl) {
    return (c.value === 'rahulSingh') ? null : {
        notCorrect: true
    };
}
```

and then import them:

```
    import {validateName} from '...';

    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
        name: ['', [validateName]]    
    });
```

This tutorial might help [How to Implement a Custom Validator Directive](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-implement-a-custom-validator-directive-confirm-password-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 1):

Below given is a directive for email validation

```
import { Directive, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Validator, AbstractControl, NG_VALIDATORS } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[validateEmail]',
  providers: [{ provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: forwardRef(() => ValidateEmail), multi: true }]
})
export class ValidateEmail implements Validator {

  constructor() { }

  validate(c: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } {
    let EMAIL_REGEXP =  /^[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+(\.[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+)*@([a-z0-9_][-a-z0-9_]*(\.[-a-z0-9_]+)*\.(aero|arpa|biz|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|mil|museum|name|net|org|pro|travel|mobi|[a-z][a-z])|([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}))(:[0-9]{1,5})?$/i;

    if (!c.value) return null;
    return EMAIL_REGEXP.test(c.value) ? null : {
      validEmail: true
    };
  }
}
```

below is another custom validation directive for match a model with another.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, forwardRef, Attribute } from '@angular/core';
import { Validator, AbstractControl, NG_VALIDATORS, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[matchControl][ngModel]',
  providers: [{ provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: forwardRef(() => MatchControl), multi: true }]
})
export class MatchControl implements Validator{

  constructor(@Attribute('matchControl') private matchControl: string) { }

  validate(c: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any; } {
    let v = c.value;
    let e = c.root.get(this.matchControl)

    return (e && v !== e.value) ? {
        match: true
    } : null;
  }
}
```

and its html as follows

```
<input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" required minlength="8" maxlength="15" [(ngModel)]="user.password" #password="ngModel">
<input name="cpassword" type="password" class="form-control" required [(ngModel)]="user.cpassword" #cpassword="ngModel" matchControl="password">
```

hope these two examples will help you